# Associative algebras with Jacobson radical of codimension 1 

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, reference-request

Is there a name for finite-dimensional associative $F$-algebras having the Jacobson radical of codimension 1. Of course they are particular local algebras and, indeed, the converse is true provided $F$ is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are local *basic* algebras.

Comment: A finite dimensional algebra is basic if modulo its radical is a direct product of copies of the base field, and in that case it is local iff there is exactly one factor.

Comment: Some people would say split basic and use basic for the radical quotient being a direct product of division rings. 